# list appending is out-of-order in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just wrote a small piece of code in tensorflow to test its multi-gpu performance, with dataset API.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4]])

print(dataset.output_types)
print(dataset.output_shapes)

iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
#next_element = iterator.get_next()

tensor_results = []
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        with tf.device("/gpu:%d" % j):
            with tf.name_scope("Tower_%d" % j) as scope:
                operand = iterator.get_next()
                tensor_result = tf.matmul(tf.reshape(operand,shape=[1,4]), tf.reshape(operand,shape=[4,1]))
                tensor_results.append(tensor_result)


tfconfig = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=True)
tfconfig.gpu_options.allow_growth=True

sess = tf.Session(config=tfconfig)

sess.run(iterator.initializer)
results = sess.run(tensor_results)
results
```

If you run it, the output is

```
[array([[16]], dtype=int32), array([[4]], dtype=int32), array([[36]], dtype=int32), array([[64]], dtype=int32)]
```

which is out-of-order, and it's different every time I run it.It's supposed to be like this:

```
[array([[4]], dtype=int32), array([[16]], dtype=int32), array([[36]], dtype=int32), array([[64]], dtype=int32)]
```

I guess the reason is because of the GPU parallelism (asynchronous computation), but I am not sure... Could anyone tell me the reason and how to resolve that?(while still maintaining GPU-level parallelism) Thanks!

Comment: This is because of  two fact  1) you haven't set the seed for `numpy` and `tf` in your code. Add these two lines in your code after import statements: `np.random.seed(1234)` and `tf.set_random_seed(1234)`. It will make sure that the execution results are same everytime. 2) Are you sure that you are not reading data from a generator?

Comment: @Nain Hi thanks for your repy! I am indeed reading from a generator "dataset.iterator"

Comment: Then make sure that the order in which elements are yield in the generator are also in the same order everytime

Comment: did the solution work?

Comment: @Nain Thanks for following up, I just noticed that I made a mistake by putting the iteration loop inside the graph (I guess in a graph, loop is not in sequence, instead is parallel). After I move the loop on top of the sess.run, it got back to order.

Comment: Can I put the points I provided into answer then?

Comment: @Nain Sure feel free to put! :)